# U2F with fat java client

Tags: java, fido-u2f

I was wondering, whether it is possible to run U2F with a fat java client, as I had no luck finding any java libraries that allowed sending queries to the authenticator token. Is such support possible or planed?

Comment: JFYI: We have added U2F support to SecureBlackbox 16, but Java API for U2F is not available. It will be available in about a month or so.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you achieve U2F javascript API into pure Java that can communicate with USB via HID, yes, it is possible. However, as I know so far there's no such JAVA libs so I'm afraid you need to implement it by yourself.
But you can do it with [C or Python](https://developers.yubico.com/Software_Projects/FIDO_U2F/U2F_Host_Libraries/). Maybe JNI as well.